# XCTestCase: Tap on cell in collectionView with IndexPath

Tags: ios, xctest

I have a collection view in my UI test and I would like to tap on cell with IndexPath 1-0. How can this cell be addressed in an UI test?

I found this, but it is not what I want: `app.collectionViews.cells.elementAtIndex(1).tap()`

Answer (score 0):

elementAtIndex is now deprecated.
You have to use elementBoundByIndex instead